# Unicorn Sync task not working in DevOps

Tags: sxa, unicorn

We have implemented CI/CD pipeline for project(Sitecore 9 Update-2 with SXA 1.7.1).

we have added Unicorn Sync task also to sync sitecore items in CD pipeline in DevOps.

while executing CD pipeline, Unicorn Sync task also succeeded but when we verify content none of them synced. it was working fine earlier but stopped all of a sudden. same unicorn configuration is working in developer's environment as usual but not in DevOps process.

could anyone please help on this on urgent basis.

thanks.

Comment: This is not really a site to come to for "help on an urgent basis". That said; you will need to share information about your configurations, logs, and what - specifically - isn't syncing, for anyone to be able to help you. Also please state your Unicorn and Rainbow versions.

Comment: these are versions. Unicorn.4.0.4 and Rainbow.2.0.1